# Can I use WebDriverWait without an ExpectedCondition in Selenium through Java?

Tags: java, selenium, lambda, pageload, webdriverwait

I have a project I'm working on using Cucumber/Selenium for front end testing. I have been told to use WebDriverWait instead of `Thread.sleep()` to complete the testing. However, in this case I am not looking for an expected condition. I literally need the test to pause while the page loads. If it searches for the xPath before waiting, it will click on the first item in a search and proceed to test the wrong things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) without using any [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) while you need the test to pause while the page loads you can also use *Java* `lambda` expression as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        .until(d -> ((JavascriptExecutor)d).executeScript("return document.readyState")
            .equals("complete"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you need to pause tour test?

If you need to wait untli element will be visible use: `new WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, String timeToWait).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement element));`

If you need to wait untli element will be clickable use: `new WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, String timeToWait).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(WebElement element));`

If you need to wait untli element will be present on the DOM use: `webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(String timeToWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Using Thread.sleep() or pause your test for a indicated time is a bad practise.

Answer (score 1):

**Use following method**  with Java + Selenium  :

```
public boolean  isPageReady(WebDriver driver){
   boolean readyStateComplete = false;
    while (!readyStateComplete){
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        readyStateComplete = executor.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
    }
    return  readyStateComplete;
}
```

**For C# + Selenium** :

```
private void WaitUntilDocumentIsReady(TimeSpan timeout){
    var javaScriptExecutor = WebDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, timeout);

    // Check if document is ready
    Func<IWebDriver, bool> readyCondition = webDriver => javaScriptExecutor
            .ExecuteScript("return (document.readyState == 'complete' && jQuery.active == 0)");
    wait.Until(readyCondition);
}
```